# Flask application factory no application found error

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a flask app but I am getting an error

```
unable to find application callable in file __init__.py
unable to load app 0 mountpoint='' callable not found or import error
appfactory
   __init__.py
```

The `__init__.py` file is.

```
 from flask import Flask

 def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello'
    return app
```

If I remove the `def create_app()` it works.
But I am unsure how to get this working within application factory.
I've even put `create_app()` at the end of the `__init__.py` file and I am getting the same error

Comment: Where are trying to use the create_app? Please provide your application folder structure as well.

Comment: @srikanth-chekuri Folder structure is `appfactory` with `__init__.py`.  I am following [link]https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/ [/link]. I am using uwsgi to start the app. `uwsgi --http-socket :9080 --plugins python3 --wsgi-file __init__.py --callable app`